# EmberJS - Call super action after promise resolves

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6, ember-cli

I am using Ember 2.6.0

I am extending a third party component that has some functionality defined in a action and I want to catch that action in my subclass, call a function that returns a promise and fire the supers action when the promise resolves.

So the third party component does this:

```
 import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
     theAction() {
         this._somePrivateFunction();
        //do other stuff
     }
  }
});
```

And in my subclass I am doing:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ThirdPartyComponent from 'path/to/component'

export default ThirdPartyComponent.extend({
  _funcThatReturnsPromise() {
     return new Ember.RSVP.Promise();
  }
  actions: {
     theAction() {
        const thePromise = this._funcThatReturnsPromise();
        thePromise.then(() => {
            // undefined!
            this._super(...arguments);
        })
     }
  }
});
```

`this._super()` does not resolve to the parent component action when called in the promises callback. I've tried storing the supers function as a property and calling it:

```
   theAction() {
            const thePromise = this._funcThatReturnsPromise();
            this.set('superFunc', this._super);
            thePromise.then(() => {
           // calls the super but "this" inside the supers action is undefined
           this._super(...arguments);
       })
   }
```

This, in addition to being ugly, results in `this` inside the supers action to be undefined. I'm not sure why that is.. looking through some docs.

There is also the option of calling `send()` in my subclasses action:

```
   theAction() {
      const thePromise = this._funcThatReturnsPromise();
      this.set('superFunc', this._super);
      thePromise.then(() => {
          //infinite loop!
          this.send('theAction');
      });
   }
```

But this of course results in an infinite loop since the function ends up calling itself.

I'm not sure how to proceed here. Could anyone tell me if there is a clean way to do what I am trying to do here? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks much!

Comment: If you were working with a real ES6 `class`, `super.theAction(…)` would work out of the box.

Comment: @Bergi yes that would be the ideal case but I am working within the confines of Emberjs component :-(

Answer (score 0):

In child component do like :

```
theAction() {
      const thePromise = this._funcThatReturnsPromise();
      let parentAction = this._super;
      let self = this;
      thePromise.then(() => {
          //parent usage
          parentAction();

          // this usage
          self.doSome();
      });
   }
```

Comment: @ Ebrahim Pasbani as I said in my question above I already tried that, `this` is undefined inside the parent action if called this way

Comment: @TheMethod No, you tried something else. you did set as a property of the component that would be wrong

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Whether you assign `this._super` to a property or a function-scoped variable it still results in `this` being undefined when `parentAction()` is called in `then()`

Comment: @ Ebrahim Pasbani Sorry for the delay in my response, I was away for some time. The above change does not solve the issue I am having. The problem is that `this` is not defined inside the parents method body when it is assigned and called like this. The parent action references `this` which, when called in this way, is `undefined`

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/15291 This is best workaround that I found.